# My turtle code has an error i cant seem to fix at the end of it

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get it to show up on turtle but I keep getting "shape_color is not defined" on line 50(second to last line)

If I change it to `box_color` I get

> line 14, in crescent
>      t.circle(width, extent=180, steps=none)
>   NameError: name 'none' is not defined

I don't understand why the rest don't get this error, please help.

```
import random
import turtle as t

def crescent(x, y, width, height, shape_color):
    t.fillcolor(shape_color)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(width, extent=180, steps=none)
    t.endfill()
    t.penup()
    t.fillcolor("white")
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()  
    t.fillcolor("white") 

def star(x, y, width, shape_color):
    t.fillcolor(shape_color)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    for s in range(5):
        t.forward(width)
        t.right(144)
    t.end_fill()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

t.colormode(255)  
t.tracer(-1)


for n in range(10):
    x = random.randint(-200, 200)
    y = random.randint(-200, 200)

    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    box_color = (r, g, b)

    width  = random.randint(5, 50) 
    height = random.randint(5, 50) 

    crescent(x, y, width, height, box_color)
    star(x, y, width, height, shape_color)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy have many mistakes:

-

Inside `for` you execute `star(x, y, width, height, shape_color)` but you didn't defive `shape_color`. You need at least:

```
shape_color = box_color
star(x, y, width, height, shape_color)
```

-

In `t.circle` you use `step=none` but it has to be `None` with upper `N`.
But you can also skip `step=None` and it will use `step=None` as default.
See documentation: [turtle - circle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle)

```
t.circle(width, extent=180)
```

-

You forgot `_` in command `t.endfill()` - it has to be `t.end_fill()`

-

Function `star` expects 4 arguments `def star(x, y, width, shape_color):` but in `for` loop you execute it with 5 arguments `star(x, y, width, height, shape_color)'. You have to remove`height`

```
shape_color = box_color
star(x, y, width, shape_color)
```

---

Full code:

```
import random
import turtle as t

def crescent(x, y, width, height, shape_color):
    t.fillcolor(shape_color)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    t.circle(width, extent=180)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    t.fillcolor("white")
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()  
    t.fillcolor("white") 

def star(x, y, width, shape_color):
    t.fillcolor(shape_color)
    t.penup()
    t.goto(x, y)
    t.pendown()
    t.begin_fill()
    for s in range(5):
        t.forward(width)
        t.right(144)
    t.end_fill()
#--------------------------------------------------------------------

t.colormode(255)  
t.tracer(-1)


for n in range(10):
    x = random.randint(-200, 200)
    y = random.randint(-200, 200)

    r = random.randint(0, 255)
    g = random.randint(0, 255)
    b = random.randint(0, 255)
    box_color = (r, g, b)

    width  = random.randint(5, 50) 
    height = random.randint(5, 50) 

    crescent(x, y, width, height, box_color)
    star(x, y, width, shape_color)
```

Comment: When I run the full code, I get the error `NameError: name 'shape_color' is not defined`.

Comment: Why did you retain the line `t.tracer(-1)`?  What does a `-1` argument to `tracer()` do?  The documentation says the argument is a nonnegative  integer.

Comment: @cdlane I checked only error messages and removed problems - I didn't check code so I keep all. [tracer](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/turtle.html#turtle.tracer) controls animation. It seems `-1` turns off animation but it doesn't turn off update() so it works much faster but you don't have to use `update()` manually. You would have to see turtle source code to check it (`turtle.__file__`).

Comment: I looked at the turtle source code before making my comment -- I see no evidence of `tracer(-1)` being documented or supported.  My guess is its behavior is unintentional and could disappear again.  Do you know of any significant turtle programs that make use of `turtle(-1)`?  I'm surprised by it.

Comment: @cdlane I saw source code too and I think `-1` wasn't expected by authors. I saw many `if self._trace > 0` and one `if self._trace:  update()` which means `if self._trace != 0: update()` and I think this combination gives unexpected effect - it stops animation but it doesn't stop update. I don't know any significant turtle program - even without `turtle(-1)` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the code has two check points.
first, change `t.fillcolor(white)` to `t.fillcolor("white")`.

Second, change `crescent(x, y, width, height, shape_color` to `crescent(x, y, width, height, box_color`. Because you assignment variable box_color, not shape_color. It's just parameter on 'crescent'

Comment: just did both now i get none is not defined

Answer (score 0):

When repeatedly laying down polygons, you might consider *stamping* instead of *drawing*.  When stamping, we create a turtle for each shape that itself has that shape.  We then move, color and size the turtle as desired and then stamp it.  This has a couple of advantages: speed; the ability to tap into graphic operations (like *shear*) that drawing can't:

```
from random import randint, random
import turtle

SHAPE_SIZE = 20

def crescent(width):
    turtle.begin_poly()
    turtle.circle(width, extent=180)
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

def star(width):
    turtle.begin_poly()
    for _ in range(5):
        turtle.forward(width)
        turtle.right(144)
    turtle.end_poly()

    return turtle.get_poly()

screen = turtle.Screen()
width, height = screen.window_width() / 2, screen.window_height() / 2

turtle.penup()  # use the 'default' turtle to create the other two turtles
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.setheading(90)
turtle.speed('fastest')

screen.register_shape('crescent', crescent(SHAPE_SIZE))
crescent_turtle = turtle.Turtle('crescent', visible=False)
crescent_turtle.speed('fastest')
crescent_turtle.penup()

screen.register_shape('star', star(SHAPE_SIZE))
star_turtle = turtle.Turtle('star', visible=False)
star_turtle.speed('fastest')
star_turtle.penup()

for _ in range(25):
    x, y = randint(-width, width), randint(-height, height)

    r, g, b = random(), random(), random()
    shape_color = (r, g, b)

    size = randint(5, 50)

    heading = [0, 180][randint(0, 1)]

    for tortoise in [crescent_turtle, star_turtle]:
        tortoise.turtlesize(SHAPE_SIZE / size, outline=1)
        tortoise.setheading(heading)
        tortoise.color(shape_color)
        tortoise.goto(x, y)
        tortoise.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

In some ways, it can simplify the logic (compare my definitions of `star()` and `crescent()` to other solutions.)  It also has its limitations, e.g. we need to work with simple polygons.

[image]